# mySQL Left outer join not selecting possible all data

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

Im trying to match both userIngredient.i_id and recipe_ingredient.i_id and match and compare all values of recipe_ingredient.i_id, the query I tried only displays all matching i_id's without the non matching i_id's, heres the data-

recipe_ingredients table:

```
+---------+------+
| post_id | i_id |
+---------+------+
| ifqnnv  | 1    |
+---------+------+
| ifqnnv  | 2    |
+---------+------+
| ifqnnv  | 3    |
+---------+------+
| ifqnnv  | 4    |
+---------+------+
```

userIngredient table:

```
+---------+------+
| user_id | i_id |
+---------+------+
| 4       | 1    |
+---------+------+
| 4       | 2    |
+---------+------+
| 4       | 3    |
+---------+------+
```

Query that I've tried:

```
SELECT userIngredients.i_id,recipe_ingredients.i_id, recipe_ingredients.recipe_id,
CASE
    WHEN userIngredients.i_id = recipe_ingredients.i_id THEN "true"
    WHEN userIngredients.i_id != recipe_ingredients.i_id THEN "false" 
    END as state
FROM userIngredients
LEFT OUTER JOIN recipe_ingredients
ON userIngredients.i_id = recipe_ingredients.i_id
WHERE userIngredients.uid = 4 AND recipe_ingredients.post_id = 'ifqnnv'
```

Output I got:

```
+------+------+-----------+-------+
| i_id | i_id | recipe_id | state |
+------+------+-----------+-------+
| 1    | 1    | ifqnnv    | true  |
+------+------+-----------+-------+
| 2    | 2    | ifqnnv    | true  |
+------+------+-----------+-------+
| 3    | 3    | ifqnnv    | true  |
+------+------+-----------+-------+
```

Desired output:

```
+------+------+-----------+-------+
| i_id | i_id | recipe_id | state |
+------+------+-----------+-------+
| 1    | 1    | ifqnnv    | true  |
+------+------+-----------+-------+
| 2    | 2    | ifqnnv    | true  |
+------+------+-----------+-------+
| 3    | 3    | ifqnnv    | true  |
+------+------+-----------+-------+
| null | 4    | ifqnnv    | false |
+------+------+-----------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the condition on the `left join`ed table to the `on` side of the `join`. Otherwise, this condition can never be fulfilled when the `left join` does not match, and the corresponding record is eliminated from the resultset.

```
SELECT 
    i.i_id,
    r.i_id, 
    r.recipe_id,
    CASE
        WHEN i.i_id = r.i_id THEN 'true'
        ELSE 'false'
    END as state
FROM 
    userIngredients u
    LEFT OUTER JOIN recipe_ingredients r
        ON i.i_id = r.i_id
        AND r.post_id = 'ifqnnv'
WHERE i.uid = 4
```

Side notes:

- meaningfull table aliases make the query more concise and easier to understand; use them at all times when more than one table is involved in the query
- the `case` expression can be simplified to `WHEN ... ELSE ...`, since both conditions being check are logically opposed
- use single quotes instead of double quotes to delimit strings; this corresponds to the SQL standard, while also some RDBMS use double quotes for identifiers
- mixing table names with camel case (`userIngredient`) and underscore separated (`recipe_ingredients`) is error prone; matter of fact, use underscore separated table and column names, since some RDBMS manage table names in a case-insenstive manner, making camel case pointless

Answer (score 0):

When using `left join`, [order matters](http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-left-join/). To get your desired result join `userIngredients` on `recipe_ingredients`